# how to can I prevent css code duplication with sass

Tags: css, sass

I am working on a project as front-end developer which has focused on client side performance.
I am using sass(scss), my approach is to convert every section to specific template with specific sass file, so I can import that template whenever I needed. sometimes some templates has divided to several component. in conclusion we have:

template -> every section : import in page

component -> some template part : include with sass mixin if needed

so if you use mixin, codes can be duplicate, as I said before I need 1 css file for every page, but I have solved the duplication of mixins, my approach is:

every mixin has a variable which say, is mixin has included yet or not. if it has included so do not include again. (mixin has @if $mixin_var==false { mixin codes }). so we have these:

template code:

```
@include component_1;
$component_1: true; // now included, this variable has declared in file _varibale.scss in top of codes
@include ...;
```

mixin code:

```
@mixin component_1 {
   @if $component_1==false {
      // mixin code here ...
   }
}
```

so if I include component_1 again in other sass file, the $component_1 is true, so mixin condition prevents it.

by this method, code duplication has solved yet.

but now I want to convert every template to single css file and finally include in page. so I cannot use variable and mixin anymore and components code duplicate again and again.
is there any approach to solve this? maybe any npm package or some other sass approach...

any help appreciated.

Comment: SCSS files are intermediate and need to be compiled. Duplication of mixins isn’t a problem to worry about.

Comment: You could also consider tools like [purgecss, uncss and purifycss](https://purgecss.com/comparison.html#uncss)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Does gulp-sass-import-once Implement my approach with mixins (component file) & @if? (preventing including one mixin twice or more)